# winapi c++ window not less than

Tags: c++, winapi, window, size

I created a main window for my program in c++ and I use mingw

```
hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        (LPCWSTR)szClassName,
        title,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1250,       // width
        700,        // height
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
```

This window is sizeable, and it's ok. But how can I make a window that has min widht and min height. So I mean that window hasn't been less than, for example: 500*500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO, sample code:

```
LRESULT HandledWidget::onGetMinMaxInfo( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool &bHandled )
{
    MINMAXINFO* mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
    bHandled = false;
    if (m_minWidth != -1) {
        bHandled = true;
        mmi->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_minWidth;
    }
    if (m_minHeight != -1) {
        bHandled = true;
        mmi->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_minHeight;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you help me? I uploaded a very simple code to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qPPA9X3a but what I have to write to the WM_GETMINMAXINFO ? I would like to set minHeight minWidht to HWND hwnd window.

Answer (score 2):

Handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In the message handler, `lParam` points to `MINMAXINFO` structure, which contains `POINT ptMinTrackSize` member. Fill it with desired size.